# How to set custom m4a format audio file as alarm tone on iPhone

Tags: iphone, alarm, ringtones, m4a

How can a custom audio file (m4a format) be set as my alarm tone on an iPhone? I am using an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to add the audio file as a custom ringtone to your iPhone. For doing so, follow the instructions in the linked answer:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/1885/279727

Once you have the custom ringtone into your iPhone (you can check the same by going to Settings app → Sounds & Haptics → Ringtone), you can also use it as an alarm tone in Clock app.

Comment: This does work for creating a manual alarm in the Clock App.  However, it is not getting it to show up in Alarm > Sleep | Wake Up > Sound & Haptics on an iPhone 13.  Anyone know how to do that?